# Nginx test another location after ^~ found

Tags: nginx, sendfile

I am using sendfile on nginx 1.4.4, php 5.5.8 (from WT-NMP) on **Windows 7**. I have those two locations in config.

```
location ^~ /upload_folder/ {
    internal;
    alias "c:/WT-NMP/WWW/m24/upload/";
}

location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|woff|ttf|svg|otf|mp3)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

When I set header as

```
X-Accel-Redirect: \upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg
```

then first location is tested and it looks like it find proper file on my disk. But then there is another testing for location, and now second location is matched but as I read in documentation, searching for location should stop because I am using **^~** prefix before **/upload_folder** location. Why nginx test location for second location? On Linux a have very similar configuration but it works as expected.

There are some most important lines from my logs:

```
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: "/"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: "upload_folder/"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: ~ "/themes/\w+/views"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: ~ "\.    (js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|woff|ttf|svg|otf|mp3)$"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: ~ "\.php$"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 using configuration "\.php$"
.
.
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi header: "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.8"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi header: "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi header: "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi header: "Pragma: no-cache"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi header: "Content-Type: image/jpeg"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi header: "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testfile.jpg""
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi header: "X-Accel-Redirect: \upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http fastcgi parser: 0
.
.
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 internal redirect: "\upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg?"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 rewrite phase: 1
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: "/"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: ~ "/themes/\w+/views"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 test location: ~ "\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|woff|ttf|svg|otf|mp3)$"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 using configuration "\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|woff|ttf|svg|otf|mp3)$"
.
.
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 try files phase: 11
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http script var: "\upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 trying to use file: "\upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg" "c:/wt-nmp/www/m24/web\upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 trying to use file: "=404" "c:/wt-nmp/www/m24/web=404"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http finalize request: 404, "\upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg?" a:1, c:2
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 http special response: 404, "\upload_folder\Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg?"
2014/03/27 14:14:04 [debug] 11116#12652: *766 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `X-Accel-Redirect: /upload_folder/Z5lvSRzMLxjNZZx6xJb70GiCTNKM8ZqP.jpg` with slash, not backslash.

Comment: Yes it should be / not \. I was using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of / so on linux this worked but on windows not. Thanks alexeyten